# Too many open files Elasticsearch & App Search

Tags: elasticsearch, app-search

I have elastic search index on linux vm.
I am getting below error, please advise how to resolve.
The index was working fine some reason the server went offline and while client app pushing data to the elastic.

I have a managed appsearch service is connected to this. below is the error trace, any help is highly appreciated. If I remove the index manually, the elastic service is stopping with an error.
It is not only one index, few indexes are having issue
the elastic version i am using is "number" : "7.5.2",

```
Caused by: java.nio.file.FileSystemException: /datadrive/data/nodes/0/indices/1x33jEA9SfavBaZavN2ksw/0/_state: Too many open
files
at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:100) ~[?:?]
at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:111) ~[?:?]
at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:116) ~[?:?]
at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.newDirectoryStream(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:432) ~[?:?]
at java.nio.file.Files.newDirectoryStream(Files.java:543) ~[?:?]
at org.elasticsearch.gateway.MetaDataStateFormat.findMaxGenerationId(MetaDataStateFormat.java:353) ~[elasticsearch-7.5.2.jar:7.5.2]
at org.elasticsearch.gateway.MetaDataStateFormat.write(MetaDataStateFormat.java:222) ~[elasticsearch-7.5.2.jar:7.5.2]
at org.elasticsearch.gateway.MetaDataStateFormat.writeAndCleanup(MetaDataStateFormat.java:185) ~[elasticsearch-7.5.2.jar:7.5.2]
at org.elasticsearch.index.seqno.ReplicationTracker.persistRetentionLeases(ReplicationTracker.java:491) ~[elasticsearch-7.5.2.jar:7.5.2]
at org.elasticsearch.index.shard.IndexShard.persistRetentionLeases(IndexShard.java:2228) ~[elasticsearch-7.5.2.jar:7.5.2]
at org.elasticsearch.index.seqno.RetentionLeaseBackgroundSyncAction.lambda$shardOperationOnPrimary$2(RetentionLeaseBackgroundSyncAction.java:137) ~[elasticsearch-7.5.2.jar:7.5.2]
at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionListener.completeWith(ActionListener.java:285) ~[elasticsearch-7.5.2.jar:7.5.2]
at org.elasticsearch.index.seqno.RetentionLeaseBackgroundSyncAction.shardOperationOnPrimary(RetentionLeaseBackgroundSyncAction.java:133) ~[elasticsearch-7.5.2.jar:7.5.2]
at org.elasticsearch.index.seqno.RetentionLeaseBackgroundSyncAction.shardOperationOnPrimary(RetentionLeaseBackgroundSyncAction.java:58) ~[elasticsearch-7.5.2.jar:7.5.2]
at org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportReplicationAction$PrimaryShardReference.perform(TransportReplicationAction.java:917) ~[elasticsearch-7.5.2.jar:7.5.2]
at org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.ReplicationOperation.execute(ReplicationOperation.java:108) ~[elasticsearch-7.5.2.jar:7.5.2]
at org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportReplicationAction$AsyncPrimaryAction.runWithPrimaryShardReference(TransportReplicationAction.java:394) ~[elasticsearch-7.5.2.jar:7.5.2]
at org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportReplicationAction$AsyncPrimaryAction.lambda$doRun$0(TransportReplicationAction.java:316) ~[elasticsearch-7.5.2.jar:7.5.2]
at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionListener$1.onResponse(ActionListener.java:63) [elasticsearch-7.5.2.jar:7.5.2]
at org.elasticsearch.index.shard.IndexShard.lambda$wrapPrimaryOperationPermitListener$22(IndexShard.java:2796) ~[elasticsearch-7.5.2.jar:7.5.2]
at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionListener$3.onResponse(ActionListener.java:113) ~[elasticsearch-7.5.2.jar:7.5.2]
at org.elasticsearch.index.shard.IndexShardOperationPermits.acquire(IndexShardOperationPermits.java:285) ~[elasticsearch-7.5.2.jar:7.5.2]
at org.elasticsearch.index.shard.IndexShardOperationPermits.acquire(IndexShardOperationPermits.java:237) ~[elasticsearch-7.5.2.jar:7.5.2]
at org.elasticsearch.index.shard.IndexShard.acquirePrimaryOperationPermit(IndexShard.java:2770) ~[elasticsearch-7.5.2.jar:7.5.2]
at org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportReplicationAction.acquirePrimaryOperationPermit(TransportReplicationAction.java:858) ~[elasticsearch-7.5.2.jar:7.5.2]
at org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportReplicationAction$AsyncPrimaryAction.doRun(TransportReplicationAction.java:312) ~[elasticsearch-7.5.2.jar:7.5.2]
at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.AbstractRunnable.run(AbstractRunnable.java:37) ~[elasticsearch-7.5.2.jar:7.5.2]
at org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportReplicationAction.handlePrimaryRequest(TransportReplicationAction.java:275) ~[elasticsearch-7.5.2.jar:7.5.2]
at org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.transport.SecurityServerTransportInterceptor$ProfileSecuredRequestHandler$1.doRun(SecurityServerTransportInterceptor.java:257) ~[?:?]
at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.AbstractRunnable.run(AbstractRunnable.java:37) ~[elasticsearch-7.5.2.jar:7.5.2]
at org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.transport.SecurityServerTransportInterceptor$ProfileSecuredRequestHandler.messageReceived(SecurityServerTransportInterceptor.java:315) ~[?:?]
at org.elasticsearch.transport.RequestHandlerRegistry.processMessageReceived(RequestHandlerRegistry.java:63) ~[elasticsearch-7.5.2.jar:7.5.2]
at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService$7.doRun(TransportService.java:752) ~[elasticsearch-7.5.2.jar:7.5.2]
at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.ThreadContext$ContextPreservingAbstractRunnable.doRun(ThreadContext.java:773) ~[elasticsearch-7.5.2.jar:7.5.2]
at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.AbstractRunnable.run(AbstractRunnable.java:37) ~[elasticsearch-7.5.2.jar:7.5.2]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[?:?]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[?:?]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830) ~[?:?]
```

Answer (score 0):

From the trace it may be because the user who runs elastic search might have a restriction on the open files it can be created. Please check it using the `ulimit` command.

Try `ulimit -a | grep open` and see if the limit exceeds. If so please increase that one and check.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried ulimit command it is showing "unlimited", seems no limit on it.  When i run  ulimit -a | grep open  the result is  1024
open files                      (-n) 1024